# Nuxt - Auth module: Authenticated requests on server side

Tags: node.js, authentication, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

A particular page needs to load some user specific data in the `fetch()` hook.

How do I access the auth token on the server side to send with this request?

Comment: express I'm assuming. And you use jwt?

Answer (score 0):

The auth module automatically exposes the token to the axios module, I did not check beforehand. Everything is working now.